# C# splitting comma delimited string in a foreach loop over anonymous type

Tags: c#, parsing, foreach, split

I'm trying to split the title of a product from something like, `Nitric Acid 70% , ACS REAGENT GRADE, 2.5 Liter(7 Lbs) Bottle` to `Nitric Acid 70%`.  In my code I first joined two collections with the customer name as the key.  Then I did a foreach loop over the class spreadlist and added the members from customers and product.  However, in `Title = record.Title,` I don't want the full title name just the first string before the first comma.  How can I make this happen?  I was trying to use .split but I don't think I'm understanding it correctly

```
private static IEnumerable<SpreadList> Combine(IEnumerable<Address> addresses, IEnumerable<Address> products)
{

    var customersandproducts = addresses.Select(x => new { x.Name, x.AddressLine1, x.AddressLine2, x.City, x.State, x.S_OrderId, x.PostalCode })
                                    .Join(products, custs => custs.S_OrderId, prod => prod.P_OrderId,
                                        (custs, prod) => new { custs.Name, prod.Title, prod.ShippingPrice, prod.ItemPrice, prod.Quantity });

    var records = new List<SpreadList>();

    foreach (var record in customersandproducts)
    {
        records.Add(new SpreadList()
        {
            Name = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(record.Name),
            Title = record.Title,
            ItemPrice = record.ItemPrice,
            ShippingPrice = record.ShippingPrice,
            Quantity = record.Quantity,
        });

    }
    return records;
}

public class SpreadList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShippingPrice { get; set; }
    public string ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but in your `records.Add(new SpreadLIst())` code block, I'd suggest:

```
Title = record.Title.Substring(0,record.Title.IndexOf(',')-1),
```

Another option is:

```
Title = record.Title.Split(',')[0]
```

Comment: I like the `.Split()` option. Also, since it is the first element in the resulting array, it should be safe as is.

Answer (score 1):

Using split is correct - split will create an array of sub-strings between the specified delimiter and all you have to do is grab the first item in that array.

```
Title = record.Title.Split(',')[0].Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a little function.  This could be a named function, or just a `Func<string, string>`:

```
Func<string, string> GetFirstStringPart = title => 
   {
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
          return null;  // or string.Empty;
      string[] stringParts = title.Split(',');
      if(stringParts.Any())
          return stringParts.First().Trim();
      else
          return null;  // or string.Empty;
  };

 foreach (var record in customersandproducts)
 {
     records.Add(new SpreadList()
     {
         Name = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(record.Name),
         Title = GetFirstStringPart(record.Title),
         ...
         . etc .
```

The advantage of using a function is that you can deal with any special cases that need separate handling, like empty strings or null strings, or any additional logic you might find you need.

Comment: Interesting approach I like this too will go over and review it!

Answer (score 0):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx:

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.

So if you want the first part of the string, you could just use `string result = record.Title.split(',')[0]`